# Is it true that if $G$ is abelian then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G)$ the center of $G$. I know that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian, but I'm wondering if the converse is true. Do you know a counterexample for this? Thanks.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then $G/Z(G)$ has one element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The center of $G$ consists of those elements $g \in G$ such that $gh = hg$ for all $h \in H$. In an abelian group, this relation *always* holds, so $Z(G) = G$. It follows that $G / Z(G)$ is the trivial group, consisting of only a single element (namely, the coset $Z(G)$). Every group with one element is cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

More interesting is the converse, the following is true: if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.